# Integer decision variables as index

Tags: integer-programming, constraint-programming

The following problem has only two integer variables; however, they appear in the index of the parameters. Appreciate it if anyone has any efficient idea to transform it into a canonical integer programming model.

$$
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&\max  \quad & (d_y - d_x)^2 \\
&&\text{s.t.} \quad & d_y - d_x \geq \alpha  \\
&&   & x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \\
\end{alignat*}
$$

Comment: $d:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed sequence?

Comment: @RobPratt. Yes.

Comment: OK, canonical integer programming does not allow an infinite amount of input.  Do you have any upper bound on $x$ and $y$?  Or maybe a formula that defines $d$?

Comment: @RobPratt. Yes. We have upper bounds on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Answering only the question in the title for google or-tools:
`def AddElement(self, index, variables, target):
    """Adds the element constraint: variables[index] == target."""`
https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model#addelement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x,y\in\{0,\dots,n\}$.  I think I would just loop over these $(n+1)^2$ pairs and keep the best one that satisfies the constraint.

But if you insist on integer programming, introduce binary variables $x_i$ and $y_i$ for $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$, with the interpretation that $d_x=\sum_i d_i x_i$ and $d_y=\sum_i d_i y_i$.  The problem is to maximize $$\left(\sum_i d_i (y_i - x_i)\right)^2$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= 1\\
\sum_i y_i &= 1\\
\sum_i d_i (y_i - x_i) &\ge \alpha
\end{align}
If you want, you can linearize the objective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any alternative for integer programming?

Comment: In constraint programming, you can use *element constraints* to use a variable as an index.